# Retrieving json Data C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, datacontractjsonserializer

Not able to retrieve json data below is the json data please suggest me.

```
{
    "creator_email": "thomas.v@almouj.com",
    "vcard_info": "BEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:2.1\r\nFN;CHARSET=utf-8:Hyder Hafir\r\nTEL;CELL;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=180,175,11,130;CHARSET=utf-8:+96891365444\r\nTEL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=240,251,12,139;CHARSET=utf-8:+96824170123\r\nTEL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=256,70,13,161;CHARSET=utf-8:2313504\r\nTEL;WORK;FAX;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=258,251,12,140;CHARSET=utf-8:+96824170038\r\nX-IS-TAKE-ADR;CHARSET=utf-8:0;0;\r\nN;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=142,248,15,79;CHARSET=utf-8:Hyder;Hafir ;;;\r\nEMAIL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=275,251,15,169;CHARSET=utf-8:oman@telephonyme.com\r\nEXCHANGEDATE:2019-06-17\r\nEXCHANGEDATE:2019-06-17\r\nAUTHOR:IntSig-iOS-iPhone\r\nADR;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=273,70,30,161,0,0,0,0;CHARSET=utf-8:;;Knowledge Oasis Muscat Muscat, Sultanate Of;;;;Oman\r\nADR;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=239,70,13,160,0,0,0,0;CHARSET=utf-8:;;First Floor, Office# 0401 Z321;;;;\r\nORG;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=57,26,11,147,141,157,15,73,158,147,15,203;CHARSET=utf-8:p.p.j L:\/uLmululjqdtu;JJL LLM;Operation Manager I\\\\ilLml Aui\r\nURL;HOMEPAGE;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=293,251,14,150;CHARSET=utf-8:www.telephonyme.com\r\nEND:VCARD",
    "front_jpg": "6X7705UC5b7Kfh8KyBQCC8EV_front.jpg",
    "creator_name": "Thomas Varghese",
    "upload_time": "1560756635574",
    "create_time": "1560756633000"
}
```

only one Array for the particular url.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question into something answerable. What does "not able to" mean, exactly? And what do you mean by _"only one Array for the particular url"_?

Comment: @Amrutha, use the "Newtonsoft.Json" -> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: Please use the below code decorate your method to return specifically data format. Such as json.
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        Product GetProduct(int ID);
We could directly get JSON data format when we return custom class, like the above.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case, using the [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library which is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET, you can deserialize your JSON string by the following code snippet provided:

A working example can be found at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FDMVhF

Working code:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json=@"{'creator_email':'thomas.v@almouj.com','vcard_info':'BEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:2.1\r\nFN;CHARSET=utf-8:Hyder Hafir\r\nTEL;CELL;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=180,175,11,130;CHARSET=utf-8:+96891365444\r\nTEL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=240,251,12,139;CHARSET=utf-8:+96824170123\r\nTEL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=256,70,13,161;CHARSET=utf-8:2313504\r\nTEL;WORK;FAX;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=258,251,12,140;CHARSET=utf-8:+96824170038\r\nX-IS-TAKE-ADR;CHARSET=utf-8:0;0;\r\nN;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=142,248,15,79;CHARSET=utf-8:Hyder;Hafir ;;;\r\nEMAIL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=275,251,15,169;CHARSET=utf-8:oman@telephonyme.com\r\nEXCHANGEDATE:2019-06-17\r\nEXCHANGEDATE:2019-06-17\r\nAUTHOR:IntSig-iOS-iPhone\r\nADR;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=273,70,30,161,0,0,0,0;CHARSET=utf-8:;;Knowledge Oasis Muscat Muscat, Sultanate Of;;;;Oman\r\nADR;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=239,70,13,160,0,0,0,0;CHARSET=utf-8:;;First Floor, Office# 0401 Z321;;;;\r\nORG;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=57,26,11,147,141,157,15,73,158,147,15,203;CHARSET=utf-8:p.p.j L:\/uLmululjqdtu;JJL LLM;Operation Manager I\\\\ilLml Aui\r\nURL;HOMEPAGE;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=293,251,14,150;CHARSET=utf-8:www.telephonyme.com\r\nEND:VCARD','front_jpg':'6X7705UC5b7Kfh8KyBQCC8EV_front.jpg','creator_name':'Thomas Varghese','upload_time':'1560756635574','create_time':'1560756633000'}";
        var Sresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(Sresponse.creator_email);
        Console.WriteLine(Sresponse.vcard_info);
        Console.WriteLine(Sresponse.front_jpg);

    }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string creator_email { get; set; }
    public string vcard_info { get; set; }
    public string front_jpg { get; set; }
    public string creator_name { get; set; }
    public string upload_time { get; set; }
    public string create_time { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
thomas.v@almouj.com
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
FN;CHARSET=utf-8:Hyder Hafir
TEL;CELL;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=180,175,11,130;CHARSET=utf-8:+96891365444
TEL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=240,251,12,139;CHARSET=utf-8:+96824170123
TEL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=256,70,13,161;CHARSET=utf-8:2313504
TEL;WORK;FAX;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=258,251,12,140;CHARSET=utf-8:+96824170038
X-IS-TAKE-ADR;CHARSET=utf-8:0;0;
N;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=142,248,15,79;CHARSET=utf-8:Hyder;Hafir ;;;
EMAIL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=275,251,15,169;CHARSET=utf-8:oman@telephonyme.com
EXCHANGEDATE:2019-06-17
EXCHANGEDATE:2019-06-17
AUTHOR:IntSig-iOS-iPhone
ADR;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=273,70,30,161,0,0,0,0;CHARSET=utf-8:;;Knowledge Oasis Muscat Muscat, Sultanate Of;;;;Oman
ADR;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=239,70,13,160,0,0,0,0;CHARSET=utf-8:;;First Floor, Office# 0401 Z321;;;;
ORG;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=57,26,11,147,141,157,15,73,158,147,15,203;CHARSET=utf-8:p.p.j L:/uLmululjqdtu;JJL LLM;Operation Manager I\\ilLml Aui
URL;HOMEPAGE;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=293,251,14,150;CHARSET=utf-8:www.telephonyme.com
END:VCARD
6X7705UC5b7Kfh8KyBQCC8EV_front.jpg
```